# Can every noun be a na-adjective?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, nouns, na-adjectives

I know that na-adjectives are nouns which can also act like adjectives by affixing themselves to nouns, but can every noun do this simply by adding な or can only certain nouns have the property of being adjectival?

For 利口 can act as a noun:

利口 n. intelligence

but can also be an adjective:

利口 an. intelligent, smart, clever, etc.

Comment: Sorry I deleted my answer because, although I think it's quite correct, I am not 100% sure. For example, I know 本当 is generally used as の adjective, but looking it up it could actually also be な adjective. I think not all nouns can be turned into adjectives this way (what would you use 家 as adjective for?). But the simple fact that you would not use it doesn't mean you can't. So I decided for now to delete the post until I find out more about it.

Comment: So what you're saying is that there are nouns which exist but wouldn't make sense as adjectives; of those that would make sense, some of them become na-adjectives, and the rest become no-adjectives?

Comment: That is my understanding, yes. Besides い-adjectives there are な- and の- (that works as suffix to nouns), but there are nouns that... well, are just nouns. However, what I'm unsure of is whether or not you can attach な-  to pretty much everything depending on the situation, even if it wouldn't be standard. For example in a use similar to English "-ish". But I suppose in that case you would use something like -っぽい, so I still think the answer is no, overall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not every noun can be a na-adjective.

---

A few examples of na-adjectives:

> **親切な**人 -- kind person
>   **安全な**国 -- safe country
>   **きれいな**人 -- beautiful person
>   **さわやかな**風 -- refreshing breeze
>   **ロマンチックな**映画 -- romantic movie
>   **健康的な**食生活 -- healthy diet

Some nouns take の instead of な, and some categorize them as no-adjectives. You'd say:

> **病気の**人 -- sick person
>   **最後の**晩餐 -- the last supper
>   **年配の**女性 -- elderly woman
>   **初期の**肺癌 -- early lung cancer
>   **灰色の**空 -- gray sky

... rather than 「病気**な**人」「最後**な**晩餐」「年配**な**女性」「初期**な**肺癌」「灰色**な**空」.

---

In phrases like 「**私の**本」(my book) 「**家の**屋根」(roof of a house) 「**日本の**文化」(Japan's culture) 「**空の**色」(color of the sky), however, 「私の」「家の」「日本の」「空の」 wouldn't be considered as no-adjectives. These phrases would be considered as "noun¹ + case particle の + noun²" ("noun² + of + noun¹") rather than "no-adjective + noun" ("~~*ish* + noun").

And, you don't say 「**私な**本」「**家な**屋根」「**日本な**文化」「**空な**色」 etc. These nouns express もの・こと rather than 状態・感情, and cannot be na-adjectives.

---

By the way...

> I know that na-adjectives are nouns which can also act like adjectives...

Not all na-adjectives are nouns, eg きれい, さわやか, 静か, 明らか, ロマンチック, ～～的(健康的, 劇的, 科学的 etc.)

---

As a side note:

You'd use "noun+な" before some words or phrases, even though the noun is not a na-adjective. In such cases the な is the 連体形 (attributive form) of the 断定の助動詞 (assertive auxiliary) or copula だ (source: 明鏡国語辞典). Some examples from the dictionary:

> Words that mainly take "noun+な":
>   だけだ -- 「年が一つ**下なだけだ**」
>   だけに -- 「相手が**子供なだけに**対応が難しい」
>   ので -- 「まだ**子供なので**理解できない」
>   のに -- 「**小学生なのに**よくやった」
>   ものか(終助詞) -- 「彼が**犯人なものか**」
>   もので -- 「まだ**学生なもので**」
>
> Words that take either "noun+な" or "noun+の" depending on the meaning:
>   あまり・上・くせに・せい・ため・つもり・はず・ようだ・わけ・わり…

So you can say 「**子供な**ので」「**小学生な**のに」「**形容詞な**わけではない」 etc. but it doesn't mean 子供, 小学生, 形容詞 are na-adjectives.

Answer (score 0):

Technically yes, because you could use the form of a noun with な in saying things like すべての名詞が ナ形容詞な わけではない*, which is equivalent to …ナ形容詞であるわけでは….

However, that's not substantially an adjective. (For the rest, Tommy answered to your question, I think.)

*; This sentence is too unsettling to rephrase as 形容詞のわけではない while 形容詞のはずがない is fine.